# php regex attribute from string

Tags: php, regex

I've got a string like this:

```
family="ABeeZee;100regular" decoration="" style="normal" txtalign="txt-left" size="14px" line="22px" padding="0px" bold="" uppercase="" color="""
```

And I want just to get the value/string inside `family`:

```
 ABeeZee;100regular
```

I know that I need to use regex but I still don't understand how to write the pattern...

I tried this without success:

```
$mystring = 'family="ABeeZee;100regular" decoration="" style="normal" txtalign="txt-left" size="14px" line="22px" padding="0px" bold="" uppercase="" color=""" '
$pattern  = '/(family)="([\'"])?((?(1).+?|[^\s>]+))(?(1)\1)"/is';
$string   = preg_replace($pattern, "", $mystring);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) instead of `preg_replace()` to grab the value.

You only have a single pattern so you don't need to use a conditional regex here.

```
preg_match('/family="([^"]+)"/', $mystring, $match);
echo $match[1]; //=> "ABeeZee;100regular"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you know a website/tuto where I can correctly learn regex because I'm very bored to don't understand...